# uwsgi failed to start with supervisord, but work just fine in command line, why?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, anaconda, uwsgi, supervisord

I had an ***Anaconda Python3.6*** installed on my *Debian7* VPS, and the ***uwsgi*** was installed through ***pip***.
It was just fine when I deployed my ***flask*** app with ***uwsgi*** in command line with the *.ini* file:

```
[uwsgi]  
master = true
processes = 1  
threads = 1  
wsgi-file = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3/myApp.py   
callable = app   
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5050       
virtualenv = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3
```

the deployment was successful:

```
root@server58 envs/p3# uwsgi myApp.ini  
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from myApp.ini  
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Wed May  3 21:38:50 2017] ***  
compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 25 April 2017 09:17:47  
os: Linux-2.6.32-042stab116.1 #1 SMP Wed May 4 16:21:02 MSK 2016  
nodename: server58.mainpacket.com  
machine: x86_64  
clock source: unix  
pcre jit disabled  
detected number of CPU cores: 1  
current working directory: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3  
detected binary path: /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi  
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options  
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***  
your processes number limit is 514887  
your memory page size is 4096 bytes  
detected max file descriptor number: 1024  
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes  
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)  
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5050 fd 3  
Python version: 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]  
Set PythonHome to /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3  
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x12e22a0  
python threads support enabled  
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections  
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds  
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores  
*** Operational MODE: single process ***  
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x12e22a0 pid: 10409 (default app)  
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***  
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 10409)  
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 10411, cores: 1)  
[pid: 10411|app: 0|req: 1/1] 113.66.169.110 () {34 vars in 680 bytes} [Wed May  3 21:44:00 2017] GET /func2?op1=sdkfh&op2=385 => generated 17 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)  
[pid: 10411|app: 0|req: 2/2] 113.66.169.110 () {34 vars in 643 bytes} [Wed May  3 21:44:01 2017] GET /favicon.ico => generated 233 bytes in 21 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

The app responds correctly, everything looks fine.
BUT when I put the deployment into ***supervisor*** with below *.conf* file:

```
[program:myApp]  
command = /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi   
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3/myApp.ini  
autostart = true  
startsecs = 5  
startretries = 3  
redirect_stderr = true  
stdout_logfile = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3/log_file  
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 1MB  
stdout_logfile_backup = 5  
stopsignal = QUIT
```

the ***uwsgi*** seemed failed to start my app, the log file said:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3/myApp.ini  
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Wed May  3 18:42:14 2017] ***  
compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 25 April 2017 09:17:47  
os: Linux-2.6.32-042stab116.1 #1 SMP Wed May 4 16:21:02 MSK 2016  
nodename: server58.mainpacket.com  
machine: x86_64  
clock source: unix  
pcre jit disabled  
detected number of CPU cores: 1  
current working directory: /  
detected binary path: /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/uwsgi  
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options  
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***   
your processes number limit is 514887  
your memory page size is 4096 bytes  
detected max file descriptor number: 1024  
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes  
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)  
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5050 fd 3  
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>  
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>  
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]  
Python version: 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]  
Set PythonHome to /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3  
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'  

Current thread 0x00007fd6e509a700 (most recent call first):
```

If I use ***gunicorn*** + ***supervisor*** to deploy, works perfect. So I believe it was about the ***uwsgi*** setting. But how come it works fine in command line and fails with ***supervisor***? Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

experimented a couple of methods, found that is a matter of working directory of uWSGI.
First, you should build uWSGI from source in the env where you will run the application later.

Activate the Env, then

> cd path-to-env 
>   wget https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.15.tar.gz
>   tar -xvzf uwsgi-2.0.15.tar.gz
>   cd uwsgi-2.0.15
>   python uwsgiconfig.py --build

Make sure copy or softlink the uwsgi to the /path-to-env/bin directory, and check out if uWSGI works.

Then remember to add 'chdir' option to the .ini file of the application. In my case:

```
[uwsgi]  
master = true
processes = 1  
threads = 1  
chdir = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3
wsgi-file = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3/myApp.py   
callable = app   
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5050       
virtualenv = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/p3
```

Set up service in Supervisor, then everything works just fine...

PS. if you build uwsgi in root env, the working directory should be /usr/local/anaconda3  .